# prevent double submission

Tags: visualforce

I'm trying to prevent a user from double submitting a visualforce page using the action status as described in this article:

[link](https://tquilamockingbird.wordpress.com/2011/11/10/salesforce-actionstatus-with-disabled-button-and-processing-image-100-on-platform/)

Here is the code in my VF page with the action status:

```
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="both">
        <apex:actionStatus id="mySaveStatus2">
            <apex:facet name="stop">
                <apex:commandButton action="{!savesubmit}" value="Submit" rerender="dummy2"  />
            </apex:facet>
                <apex:facet name="start">
                    <apex:commandButton value="Processing..." status="mySaveStatus2" disabled="true" />
                </apex:facet>
        </apex:actionStatus>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"  />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

The action status is not working and my VF page does not redirect to the next page upon clicking the save button.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Try adding a `status="mySaveStatus2"` to you command button

Comment: Added as answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command button is not using the status when it submits the request as you are missing the required parameter:

Try adding a status="mySaveStatus2" to you command button

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:page><apex:form id="formId">
    <apex:actionStatus id="status">
        <apex:facet name="start">
            <div style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; opacity: 0.75; z-index: 1000; background-color: grey;">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
            <div style="position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; z-index: 1001; margin: 22% 42%">
                <img src="{!$Resource.loader_logo}" width="80" height="80" / >
            </div>
        </apex:facet>
    </apex:actionStatus>
    ..........
    <apex:commandButton value="Insert Report" action="{!insertData}" >
        <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" status="status" reRender="formId" />
    </apex:commandButton>
    ...........
</apex:form></apex:page>
```

Comment: Please do not post a code dump. If this code helps answer the problem, explain what you are doing and why using an **[edit]**.